# ipad drag and drop

Tags: jquery, ipad

I need to implement drag and drop for Ipad.

I tried this solution:
http://www.gotproject.com/blog/post2.html

But since I am using JQuery myself, it conflicts and does not work.

How can I use JQuery drag and drop for IPad?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you aren't using jQuery UI, use the fork I created https://github.com/mikeangstadt/jquery-ui-touch-punch.git to hook up touch handler's using jQuery by firing the already defined mouse events.

Works well on iOS6, haven't tested for Android or others.

Answer (score 18):

**Working :**

Firstly, use jquery UI http://jqueryui.com/demos/ for drag and drop functionality

and then add this script https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch for playing it in Ipad or Iphone.

Hope it helps.

Comment: unfortunately this disabled the scroll functionality if you have a lot of draggable elements...

Answer (score 3):

This looked decent.

http://popdevelop.com/2010/08/touching-the-web/

Answer (score 2):

Apple has a Section called "Handling Multi-Touch Events" here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/multitouch_background/multitouch_background.html

It is the official Apple guide on how you can handle almost all of your touch events with the standard controls and gesture recognizers in UIKit.

Answer (score 2):

Confirmed that furf's jquery-ui-touch-punch works on the iPad.

Getting it to work is as easy as including "jquery.ui.touch-punch.js" after you've included jquery-ui and jquery itself. For example:

HTML:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js"></script>

    <!-- touch capability for tablets/phones -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.js"></script>
</head>
```

Javascript:

```
//
// assume that html_string is a valid string
// containing some element you want to be draggable
// which needs to be added to the DOM
//
function addItemToUIList (list, html_string) {
    var item = $(list).append (html_string);

    // now, using jqui and touch-punch, we can make it draggable
    item.draggable ();
}
```

Now "item" can be dragged around on screen on the ipad as well as in chrome on the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on a fix to this issue check my github: https://github.com/youryss/fixdragtablet

I hope it works for you

Comment: Please include code in your answer. We are lazy and don't like clicking links.

Comment: I can't post the entire code cus it's a mix of solutions :/ but take a look I think it will work for you :), I here to questions