# strange issue: Variable is not defined on touchscreen

Tags: jquery, html, css, multi-touch

I'm experiencing very strange behaviour on a webpage I've been building.
I want to implement an undo-function for when the user removes a picture and want to undo that action and put the picture back.

Right now the user can drag the image to the left and drop it in a bin. When he clicks the UNDO-button, the picture should be restored on the last known position.

In the code I'm adding the position and the name of the object to an array:

```
deletedProfiles.push({"id": CandidateId, "posX": PositionX, "posY": PositionY});
```

Afterwards, when the user hits the UNDO-button, I'm reading out the last values of the array and using that to restore the DIV and to reposition it again on the last know position:

```
// GET THE VALUES FROM THE LAST PROFILE OUT OF THE HISTORY
historyId = deletedProfiles[deletedProfiles.length-1].id;
historyPositionX = parseInt(deletedProfiles[deletedProfiles.length-1].posX);
historyPositionY = parseInt(deletedProfiles[deletedProfiles.length-1].posY);

// RESTORE THE PROFILE
$('#' + historyId).removeClass("grey").addClass("color");
$('#' + historyId).fadeIn(250);
$('#' + historyId).offset({ top: historyPositionY, left: historyPositionX});
```

Now when I open this page on my laptop and I perform the needed actions, it works perfectly.
When I use the touchscreen that is connected to my laptop and I just refresh the same page, `deletedProfiles[deletedProfiles.length-1].id` returns as "undefined".

On my tablet it has the same issue, it doesn't recognize the variable.

I've already made sure that the variables are the first thing which are loaded onto the page to prevent any calls made to variables that don't exist yet. Also when you click on the UNDO-button, it does state that there is 1 element in the array.

I've tried to reproduce it in a fiddle but without any luck. I've uploaded a slimmed down version of the page on http://bit.ly/1AR6l0Z

Just some instructions to test it:
- Drag the picture to the left and drop it in the grey area which will appear and drop it in. The picture will disappear.

- Click on the UNDO-button which will appear as soon as you have dropped the picture.
- Alertboxes will popup with info.

If anybody has an idea on why this is happening, please do enlighten me.

For your information: I'm using Chrome as browser.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if your "drag and drop" event works on your tablet, it may not be triggered and not push your array ?

I found this issue that might be similar 
[ipad drag and drop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279477/ipad-drag-and-drop)

Sorry if it didn't help I'm pretty new here :)

Comment: It does because the picture is fading out. When you press the UNDO-button it also shows that there is 1 element in the array. So that part is working.